# Typescript Filter - How to seperate matches in array

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter

Im using the filter function to return an array matching a certain option. The array which returns looks like this:

This is what I used:

```
const arrayMatchedItems = new Array<DetailedUsageVoiceModel[]>();

voiceFilterObj.arrayCallType[0].callTypes.forEach((callType) => {
        const matchedItems = callDataList.filter(value => value.type === callType);
        arrayMatchedItems.push(matchedItems);
      });
      console.log("Resultado 2: ", arrayMatchedItems);
```

---

```
Resultado 2:  
(2) [Array(1), Array(3)]
0: [DetailedUsageVoiceModel]
1: (3) [DetailedUsageVoiceModel, DetailedUsageVoiceModel, DetailedUsageVoiceModel]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The position 1 in the array is agrouping 3 together because the **type** matches:

```
Resultado 2:  
(2) [Array(1), Array(3)]
0: Array(1)
0: DetailedUsageVoiceModel {_duration: 123, _cost: 0, _type: "Serv. Información", _usageDate: Moment, _usageType: "VOZ", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
1: Array(3)
0: DetailedUsageVoiceModel {_duration: 1314, _cost: 0, _type: "Numeración corta", _usageDate: Moment, _usageType: "VOZ", …}
1: DetailedUsageVoiceModel {_duration: 78, _cost: 0, _type: "Numeración corta", _usageDate: Moment, _usageType: "VOZ", …}
2: DetailedUsageVoiceModel {_duration: 123, _cost: 0, _type: "Numeración corta", _usageDate: Moment, _usageType: "VOZ", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Resultado 2:  
    (4) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
    0: [DetailedUsageVoiceModel]
    1: [DetailedUsageVoiceModel]
    2: [DetailedUsageVoiceModel] 
    3: [DetailedUsageVoiceModel]
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Note that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and therefore if there is a JavaScript solution, it will work in TypeScript. Consider doing some research into JavaScript solutions to this problem.

Comment: instead of using array use object with keys as types

Comment: The code here does not constitute a [mcve] so I can't be sure if this suggestion will work: `const arrayMatchedItems = callDataList.filter(value => voiceFilterObj.arrayCallType[0].callTypes.indexOf(value.type) >= 0);`.  If so, please modify the question to be a minimal reproducible example and I will be happy to post an answer.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz that worked perfectly, add it as an awnser so I can upvote you, thanks!